# Set if condition with wp_nav_menu

Tags: wp-query, menus, pages, navigation

I have created one new menu and add bellow code in footer.php to display my menu

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'footer-cn', 'menu_id' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => 'ft-nav' ));
```

Currently I did not add any pages inside this menu so I want to set some condition if any pages available inside `footer-cn` then display menu.

I want to set condition something this:

```
<?php
    if(){ // Some condition
        wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'footer-cn', 'menu_id' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => 'ft-nav' ));
    }
?>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Short answer is "yes - absolutely". If you edit your question to include the condition details, you'll likely have a response with how to accomplish the condition test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use conditional here to hide your nav menu when it is empty.

Have a look at [`wp_nav_menu( $args );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). It accepts the following arguments

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

The important one here is `'fallback_cb'`

> $fallback_cb (string) (optional)
>
> If the menu doesn't exist, the
>   fallback function to use. Set to false for no fallback. Note: Passes
>   $args to the custom function.
>
> Default: wp_page_menu

So to hide a menu when it is empty, you can simply just add this to your arguments

```
'fallback_cb' => false
```

So your end code should be

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'footer-cn', 'menu_id' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => 'ft-nav',  'fallback_cb' => false));
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help